Clarifying some questions about `std::shared_ptr<T>`
I have a class Box, and assume that it is rather heavy weight (eg. memory intensive + dynamically allocated data). I have another class BoxWrapper, which as the name suggests is essentially a wrapper on top of Box. Currently, its bare-bones implementation is as follows:
class BoxWrapper
{
public:
   BoxWrapper(const Box& box)
      : m_Box(box)
   {
   }

private:
   Box m_box;
};

In my application, we instantiate the Box as a private variable and it is accessed + modified throughout the application lifetime. However, I become concerned when my application tries to construct a BoxWrapper; clearly it performs a copy of the Box and I'm worried about a potential performance hit since Box can be very large.
How can I deal with this? My first thought was maybe I can add a BoxWrapper(Box&& box) but that would mean I would need to std::forward my box, which is not acceptable since the box will still be needed later in the application.
I come from a C background so I thought another solution would be to have BoxWrapper store a pointer Box* m_box instead! This would avoid a costly copy. However, since this is cpp I thought maybe I should use a smart pointer instead. Something like std::shared_ptr<Box> seems to work. This is where I'm running into questions.

When I'm reading cppreference for shared_ptr, I'm having trouble understanding the various symbols. I have a basic understanding of templates, but if we're dealing with std::shared_ptr<T>, then why are so many template <class Y>'s in the picture? What does Y mean in the context of us trying to create a pointer for T?

I realised that I can construct a shared pointer as so: auto box_ptr = std::make_shared<Box>(box); where box was previously defined. I assume I can do this because of the constructor (9) from cppreferences since box is an lvalue?

Finally, I'm not even sure if shared_ptr could help me much here. If I construct a shared pointer with an lvalue, I would still be making a copy of the Box. I still can't use std::forward as the Box cannot be moved and is still being used by the application later. Is this the correct understanding? It looks like I'm better off just using a raw pointer.



shared_ptr is simply a ref-counted thing to hold a T* (which, in your case, is a Box*). It does not make copies of your box, just a copy of the pointer. If it requires a special deleter you’ll need to provide a specialized version of shared_ptr for that too. But otherwise it acts very much like your idea of Box* m_box.

From the page you linked to For the purposes of the description below, a pointer type Y* is said to be compatible with a pointer type T* if either Y* is convertible to T* or Y is the array type U[N] and T is U cv [] (where cv is some set of cv-qualifiers).

The first question you should ask yourself is "how the lifetime of Box object is managed"? Or, for a shorter formulation, who owns the Box? The answer dictates the choice of implementation.

The most fundamental question should should be asking is why you are apparently happy with two totally different solutions. In the first case you are copying box, so you have two independent boxes, but now you are considering a solution where you have two objects sharing a single box. I'm not saying either is right or wrong, just that they are fundamentally different and you have jumped from one to the other apparently without any pause for thought.

If all you have is a lvalue Box, shared_ptr should not be used. To use shared_ptr you have to make sure the very first instance of box is created in the free store, preferably using make_shared (make_unique is also possible but more delicate). Using a shared_ptr with default deleter to refer to an automatic Box variable, for example, is wrong.

Y is related to the constructor argument, and T is related to the pointer itself.

How many different Boxes your application can have? Can one Box by managed by 2 different wrappers? Do you want to be able to copy your BoxWrapper? If you want to be able to copy it, should it be shallow, or deep copy? Depending on the answers, one of the following approaches will work for you: Box& _boxRef;, std::unique_ptr<Box> _boxUptr;, std::shared_ptr<Box> _boxSPtr;.

You seem need to start from The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List.

The purpose of shared_ptr is multiple owners of the same object. The object will be actually destroyed only when every owner will destroy it.

Why do you think you need a shared_ptr in the first place? You are not constructing a Box, you just want to have a reference to it. So just use a Box& m_box; or alternatively std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<Box>> if you need to take care of such cases.

Re: "it performs a copy of the Box and I'm worried about a potential performance hit" -- if you need two boxes you need two boxes; if you don't, you don't. This is a design question; there's no coding solution if copying is necessary and expensive.

This all comes down to the ownership of Box and its lifetime.
To start off, as you noted yourself, the current BoxWrapper has a Box copy. This means that once the Box has been wrapped you have an entirely new Box, not connected with the original Box, that lives exactly as long as the wrapper does. But, as you noted, this also requires a (possibly expensive) copy.
One possible way to avoid the copy is to change the wrapper to store a pointer (or reference, preferred in C++) to the Box. This avoids the Box copy, but, in C++ as in C, you must take care here because your pointer (or reference) is only valid as long as the original Box is still alive - and once that Box dies, you do NOT get any notification or have any way to detect from the wrapper that it no longer points to a valid Box.
If your program is structured so that no BoxWrapper can or will outlive the Box it contains, then this is a good, simple, and low cost solution to your problem.
However, if your Box and BoxWrapper lifetimes are more complex so that it is hard to guarantee that Box outlives BoxWrapper, then std::shared_ptr may be  a better solution.
But you must be aware that then std::shared_ptr takes ownership of the Box, so that you probably should no longer should have plain Box variables anywhere. If you have a Box myBox and:

Do a ... = std::make_shared<Box>(myBox); then it will create a copy of your Box and manage that copy with the std::shared_ptr. If you only use that std::shared_ptr going forward, then you don't get any more expensive Box copying, but you may as well not have the myBox. On the other hand, if you keep myBox and make several std::shared_ptr from that, then you are back to the original problem.
Do a ... = std::shared_ptr<Bla>(&myBox); then there is no copy (yay!), instead the std::shared_ptr tries to take ownership of the object you just gave it a pointer to (oh shit!). Which is liable to go very wrong, unless this is an object you have created on the heap for just this purpose; specifically, std::shared_ptr must be allowed to delete the object when the last std::shared_ptr to it goes out of scope - so do not give it something on the stack, or an object you are also going to delete. Perhaps you already knew this, but I thought it was important enough to include as a warning

TL;DR: I think you should go for a wrapper with a Box reference if possible, or, if you really need more complex lifetime handling, move everything over to std::shared_ptr<Box>. But it all comes down to your object lifetimes.



if we're dealing with std::shared_ptr, then why are
so many template 's in the picture? What does Y mean in the
context of us trying to create a pointer for T?


Y is related to T in such a way that a T* can point to it. Perhaps it is derived from T? Or it is just plain T itself.


I realised that I can construct a shared pointer as so: auto box_ptr =
std::make_shared(box); where box was previously defined. I assume
I can do this because of the constructor (9) from cppreferences since
box is an lvalue?


Note that make_shared not only creates a pointer, it also makes its own copy of what it points to. It can share ownership with other shared_ptrs pointing to the same object. It can not share with non-owned objects, like a Box stored on the stack.


Finally, I'm not even sure if shared_ptr could help me much here. If I
construct a shared pointer with an lvalue, I would still be making a
copy of the Box.


Like I said above, make_shared creates copies. :-)

I still can't use std::forward as the Box cannot be
moved and is still being used by the application later. Is this the
correct understanding?

Sort of. If you already have a copy somewhere, and its liftime is assured, you don't need the shared_ptr machinery.
shared_ptrs are most useful when there are several potential owners and you don't know their lifetimes exactly.
In a Kate Gregory video shes uses an example of screen windows all showing the same picture. Each window object holds a shared_ptr to the image, and when the last window is closed - in any order - the image bitmap is automatically deleted.


It looks like I'm better off just using a raw
pointer.


Yes, or use a reference, like you already do.  :-)
